# ConstraintLayout editor CPU usage/slowness

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I am having issues with the layout editor on Android studio while using constraint layout. It seems to work fine on simple layouts, however when the layout has a large number of elements, the CPU usage shoots up to 100% and there is a 3-4 second delay in any action on the editor. This makes the visual editor almost unusable. Does anyone have a similar issue on complex layouts using constraint layout?

I'm using Android Studio 2.3.1.

My PC is a 2015 MacBook Pro, 2.8 Ghz Core i7, 16GB ram.

Comment: I'm also experiencing this, using Android Studio 3.0.1. It seemed to become a problem when I started using a lot of chains in the layout.